# What keeps resetting the transient hostname on Raspbian Bullseye?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Running Raspbian 11 Bullseye on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2

I noticed (from getting a different prompt when re-logging in at one point) that something keeps futzing with the "transient" hostname, resetting it to `localhost`:

```bash
# hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: hg
Transient hostname: localhost
         Icon name: computer
        Machine ID: 5b33bf9eb66d440aaa7ed366eadef623
           Boot ID: 4b4c2bfec1f247648d815598a227a284
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
            Kernel: Linux 6.1.19-v7+
      Architecture: arm
```

If I manually set it myself, as with

```bash
# hostnamectl set-hostname --transient --static hg
```

and set up something to watch, something changes the transient hostname back to `localhost`, seemingly at random.

What's doing this, and how can I keep it from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Per the man-page that's `hostnamectl --transient --static hostname hg` There is no ``set-hostname` command to `hostnamectl` See [man 1 hostnamectl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostnamectl.1.html) You can always do it the old way too `# hostname hg` then `# echo "hg" > /etc/hostname` and update `/etc/hosts` to contain the line `127.0.0.1 hg.yourdomain.tld localhost hg` and do the same for the `::1` address for IPv6 loopback.

Comment: I disagree.  The manpage for `hostnamectl` very clearly identifies "`set-hostname NAME`" as valid; it's the second command listed, after `status`.

Comment: And `/etc/hosts` includes `localhost` for IPAs `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.  Which is as it should be  The local address will always be there, and should always be named `localhost`.  `hg` is known in DNS for the non-local address, so also assigning it in `/etc/hosts` to `127.0.0.1` will not make things any more simple; rather the opposite, ISTM.  What is deciding that the transient hostname should be changed from whatever it might have been to `localhost`, and why?  `/etc/hostname` **does** contain `hg`.

Comment: It's an issue because the `.bash_history` file name includes the hostname, as does the `bash` prompt.  Having those both use `localhost` defeats the purpose, but I believe it's the value of `HOSTNAME` envariable at time of login that sets what will be used.  So it needs to be something a) predictable, b) persistent, and c) specific to that particular host.  Does that help?

Comment: I have been unable to track down what's been frobbing the hostname, so I've worked around it with a `cron` job to check and reset the name to the system's actual name, and not the navel-gazing value <grin> `localhost`.